# How to make this clean hex shape with complex shape inside it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, transform

How to make this hexagonal shape with complex geometrical shape inside it?

[image: this is logo from zynga bank]

I try to make this with this shape

[image]

I experiment with transform effect for 2 hours still have no idea how to make this.

[image]

Thank you :(((

Answer (score 4):

1. Draw your basic triskelion shape, as you have in your second image;
2. Copy it, but rather than using 'Paste', use 'Paste in Front' <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd>;
3. Rotate the copy 60 degrees;
4. Select both shapes;
5. Choose the Blend tool (<kbd>W</kbd>);
6. Click once on an anchor on the end of a triskelion leg of the first shape;
7. Then click on the anchor in the concave corner of the *other* shape;
8. Double-click the Blend tool icon in the toolbox;
9. Choose 'specified steps' and '8' for the amount of steps in the popup that appears.

The example also has the front and back shapes with different stroke thicknesses. You can change those beforehand, but you can also double click the blend with the Selection tool to enter its isolation mode and change the shapes and have the blend update as you go.

Comment: it can also be rotated 90 degrees instead, it might be easier with just the shift + mouse

Comment: @Luciano I'm not so sure... 90 deg (clockwise) will have the original triskelion's arms point right, to bottom left and to top left. That's not what you want for this figure.

Comment: oh sorry, I meant 180 degrees

Comment: The hard part here in this specific case is that it's *extremely hard* to make the original shape *without* any double or extraneous anchors, as Pathfinder or Join are wont to do. Too many anchors, and the Blend is frakked up.

Comment: @Vincent if you notice the original has a messed up corner